# При использовании "use strict" код Word Rotator работает некорректно

Tags: javascript, jquery

Проблема: при использовании "use strict" данный код Word Rotator работает, но некорректно, появляется мерцание, непонятная прозрачность, как можно решить этот вопрос?

```
    var ut_word_rotator = function() {

        var ut_rotator_words = [
            'Text 1',
            'Text 2',
            'Text 3'
        ] ,
        counter = 0;                

        setInterval(function() {
        $(".hero-title").fadeOut(function(){
                $(this).html(ut_rotator_words[counter=(counter+1)%ut_rotator_words.length]).fadeIn();
            });
        }, 3000 );
    }

    ut_word_rotator();
```

Answer (score 0):

Без понятий, что за word ротатор, но покажите более живой пример. 
И в fadeOut() первым всегда передается длительность анимации, а потом callback.

Comment: можно на примере?

Comment: вы о чем? я вас не понимаю.